# Is there a shortcut key for opening Control Panel?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, control-panel

Is there a shortcut key for opening Control Panel in Windows 10?

Similar to something like <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> for opening Settings.

Looking for <kbd>WIN</kbd> key shortcut only.

Registry edits are welcome as well, familiar to them.

Also I don’t prefer any 3rd party applications.

Answer (score 2):

Since windows removed Control Panel from Power menu, you can simply add your own.

> Find it in start by writing 'control' -> right-click -> Open file
>   location -> right-click on Control panel icon -> Properties ->
>   Shortcut key -> add new key

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a shortcut key for opening Control Panel in Windows 10?

> <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd> - Control **P**anel

Source [94 Shortcuts for Microsoft Windows 10 (Windows)](https://shortcutworld.com/Windows/win/Microsoft-Windows_10_Shortcuts)

Comment: I am not seeing that option on 1903 or 1909. Why would they remove such a useful shortcut? :(